# can't install gem therubyracer to twitter-bootstrap-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, therubyracer

I'm trying to install:

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", :group => :assets
```

But when I use **bundle install**, it's happened:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using i18n (0.6.1)
Using multi_json (1.3.6)
Using activesupport (3.2.8)
Using builder (3.0.2)
Using activemodel (3.2.8)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.1)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.1)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.1.3)
Using actionpack (3.2.8)
Using mime-types (1.19)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.8)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.33)
Using activerecord (3.2.8)
Using activeresource (3.2.8)
Using authlogic (3.1.3)
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Using json (1.7.5)
Using rdoc (3.12)
Using thor (0.16.0)
Using railties (3.2.8)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using commonjs (0.2.6)
Using jquery-rails (2.1.2)
Using less (2.2.2)
Using less-rails (2.2.3)
Using libv8 (3.3.10.4)
Using metaclass (0.0.1)
Using mocha (0.12.3)
Using mysql2 (0.3.11)
Using nifty-generators (0.4.6)
Using bundler (1.2.0.rc.2)
Using rails (3.2.8)
Using sass (3.2.1)
Using sass-rails (3.2.5)
Installing therubyracer (0.10.2) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating v8-i386-mingw32.def
compiling rr.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
rr.cpp: In function 'VALUE rr_define_finalizer(VALUE, void*, VALUE)':
rr.cpp:48:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
In file included from rr.cpp:3:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Value,
 VALUE = long unsigned int]':
rr.cpp:159:37:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_array.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_array.cpp:1:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Array,
 VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_array.cpp:13:36:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_callbacks.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_context.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_context.cpp:2:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Contex
t, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_context.cpp:15:39:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Object
Template, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_context.cpp:22:143:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Value,
 VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_context.cpp:23:110:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_date.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_date.cpp:4:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Date,
VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_date.cpp:21:52:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_debug.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_exception.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_exception.cpp:3:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::StackT
race, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_exception.cpp:48:44:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::StackF
rame, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_exception.cpp:68:43:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
v8_exception.cpp: At global scope:
v8_exception.cpp:10:24: warning: '<unnamed>::stack' defined but not used
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_external.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_external.cpp:4:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Extern
al, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_external.cpp:51:60:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
v8_external.cpp: At global scope:
v8_external.cpp:10:9: warning: '<unnamed>::references' defined but not used
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_function.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_function.cpp:5:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Functi
on, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_function.cpp:13:40:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Array,
 VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_function.cpp:23:55:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::String
, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_function.cpp:49:51:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_handle.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_locker.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
v8_locker.cpp: In function 'VALUE<unnamed>::Lock::Delete(VALUE)':
v8_locker.cpp:45:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
v8_locker.cpp: In function 'VALUE<unnamed>::Unlock::Delete(VALUE)':
v8_locker.cpp:85:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_message.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_message.cpp:2:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Messag
e, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_message.cpp:10:38:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_object.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_object.cpp:1:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Object
, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_object.cpp:17:39:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_script.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_script.cpp:2:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Script
, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_script.cpp:25:56:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_string.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_string.cpp:3:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::String
, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_string.cpp:13:38:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_template.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_template.cpp:2:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Templa
te, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_template.cpp:42:39:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Object
Template, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_template.cpp:45:45:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Functi
onTemplate, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_template.cpp:48:47:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Data,
VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_template.cpp:54:53:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_try_catch.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_v8.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_value.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_value.cpp:1:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Value,
 VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_value.cpp:10:37:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_weakref.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++
compiling v8_try_catch.cpp                                                                                                                                           cc1plus.exe: warning: command line optcc1
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo                                                                                                                   r C/Ob
r C/ObjC but not for C++                                                                                                                                          valid                              cc1plus.e
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid                                                                                                              for C/ObjC b
for C/ObjC but not for C++                                                                                                                                            compiling v8_v8.cpp      g++.exe: unreco
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'                                                                                                                          tion "-Wdeclaration-after-compiling v8_v8.cp
compiling v8_v8.cpp                                                                                                                                                                      cc1plus.exe: warning:
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo                                                                                                 r C/ObjC but not for C++
r C/ObjC but not for C++                                                                                                                                               g++.exe: unrcc1plus.exe: warning: comma
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid                                                                                            for C/ObjC but not for C++
for C/ObjC but not for C++                                                                                                                                        valid fo   g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rd
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'                                                                                                                                  compiling v8_value.cpp
compiling v8_value.cpp                                                                                                                                                 cc1plus.exe: warning: command line opti
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo                                                                             1:r C/ObjC but not for C++
r C/ObjC but not for C++                                                                                                                                          c1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-W
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid                                                                              C/ObjC but not for C++
for C/ObjC but not for C++                                                                                                                                         included from v8_value.cpp:1:0:
In file included from v8_value.cpp:1:0:                                                                                                                           h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_han
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Value,                                                                              unsigned int]':
 VALUE = long unsigned int]':                                                                                                                                     37:   instantiated from here
v8_value.cpp:10:37:   instantiated from here                                                                                                                      warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer w
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-alias
ing rules                                                                                                                                                         ion '-rdynamic'
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_weakref.cpp                                                                                                                                          ine option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" i
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid fo
r C/ObjC but not for C++                                                                                                                                          tion "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is va
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid
for C/ObjC but not for C++
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
linking shared-object v8.so
g++.exe: c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4/lib/libv8/build/v8/libv8.
a: No such file or directory
make: *** [v8.so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0
.10.2 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.10.2/ext/v8/gem_
make.out
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.10.2), and Bundler cannot continue
.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.10.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Here are some notable steps that I ran before the error. They worked fine:

```
gem install libv8
```

**I'm using Windows and ruby 1.9.3p194**

Someone could save me please? *-*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is not a supported platform for therubyracer: https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/194

Answer (score 0):

I got this mistake before, try to use Cygwin (it is a very powerful tool to simulate Linux in window)  or install Ubuntu, Mac instead, or install Wubi, it's good!